# How to understand "multimodal" RNNs for image captioning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network

This paper [Deep Visual-Semantic Alignments for Generating Image Descriptions](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cvpr2015.pdf) on image captioning proposed a Multimodal Recurrent Neural Network architecture.

From my understanding, the multimodal RNN is essentially a language model conditioned on a given image vector.

Somehow I'm confused what "multimodal" refers to in that paper, how do I interpret this? Does it mean that since it is conditioned on an image vector, the language model becomes multimodal?

Answer (score 0):

Multimodal literally means "multiple modes", where vision, language, audio, lidar, etc data are each a different *mode* of information provided by the world. So you can call any model which deals with more than one mode of sensory input a multimodal model.

Comment: Thanks, I mean I basically understand the concept of a multimodal distribution, in that paper the multimodal RNN model outputs a categorical probability every step (just like many other RNN models), so I'm confused how the name multimodal should be understood in that context.

Comment: @dontloo multimodal is an overloaded term. the other sense of the word is a distribution with multiple peaks. that is not what is meant in this paper.